# Why is simulation-based security for functional encryption impossible in the standard model?

Tags: encryption

Boneh et al.(Functional Encryption Definitions and Challenges) present that simulation-based security for functional encryption is impossible in the standard model. 
I can not understand this.

In addition, why can we construct a simulation-based secure scheme where a bounded number of ciphertext queries is necessary when considering adaptive queries in the standard model.